# Change which libxml2 version PHP uses

Tags: php, xml-rpc, libxml2, php-5.6

A little bit of intro. I'm using `xmlrpc_server_call_method` to parse through an XML request and perform the action specified in the XML on the data contained in the XML. The XMLs I need to process are larger than 10MB, largely due to one extremely long line of text and so I need to compile libxml2 with a modified parserInternals.h file. I have successfully compiled libxml2 and got the libxml2.so, libxml2.so.2, and libxml2.so.2.9.7 files as a result.

The problem I'm having is getting PHP to recognize those as the libxml2.so to use. Do I have to compile php-xmlrpc as well? I've replaced every libxml2.so on my server with the new libxml2.so's, and PHP still thinks there is a 2.9.1 somewhere on my system (according to `phpinfo()`).

Also, `ldconfig` shows `libxml2.so.2 -> libxml2.so.2.9.7`, but doesn't show libxml2.so at all.

The output of ldd xmlrpc.so:

```
libxml2.so.2 => /lib64/libxml2.so.2 (memory address goes here)
```

/lib64 is linked to /usr/lib64, and the libxml2.so.2 in that directory links to libxml2.so.2.9.7, the result of compiling the modified libxml2.

Thanks

Comment: What says `ldd xmlrpc.so`? This should show you, if the shared library itself loads libxml as shared lib or if libxml was linked into xmlrpc statically (in the latter case you would need to compile xmlrpc again).

Comment: To overcome the 10 MB limit, it should be possible to parse XML documents with the [`LIBXML_PARSEHUGE` flag](http://www.php.net/manual/en/libxml.constants.php) without having to recompile the library.

Comment: @nwellnhof I agree that it should be possible, but the xmlrpc methods do not accept this flag. Using this flag with simplexml_load_string() does parse the XML, but xmlrpc handles base64 nicely, and I don't want to have to replicate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to manually remake the symbolic links. They were pointing to the correct place, but for some reason php-fpm in /proc/pid/map_files/blah still had symbolic links to libxml2.so.2.9.1, even after a restart with `systemctl restart rh-php56-php-fpm`. I remade the symbolic links with `ln -sf libxml2.so.2.9.7 libxml2.so.2` and restarted the php-fpm service again, and voila.

Thank you to GhostGambler for teaching me about ldd. That was a very helpful lesson.

EDIT: For reference, I used the following command to find out if there were processes still using the older libxml2 library:

```
find / -exec ls -ald {} ';' 2>/dev/null | grep '\-> /path/to/library_of_interest.so'
```

This is slow... so it's better to just start in /proc and be patient.